# ¿Cual es la propiedad para llamar el valor de un item seleccionado de una lista?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Me surgió una duda mientras desarrollaba este código, hice una lista desplegable en el que cada uno tiene el valor de un ID.

Ahora quiero desarrollar una condición para deshabilitar mas listas desplegables y habilitarlas hasta que seleccionen un item donde su valor `ID > 0`.

Mi problema es que no se que propiedad necesito para llamar a dicho item para comprobar su valor cuando lo seleccionen, mientras investigaba me enrede.

```
//un poco de idea de como esta desarrollado mi Dropdownlist

private void Lista1()

{
   //codigo resumido como el de matrix

    string selectSQL = "SELECT ID, Nombre FROM Muestra";

            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = reader["Nombre"] + "";
            newItem.Value = reader["ID"].ToString();
            listauno.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

---

```
//ejemplo de la condicion a formar

private void Habilitar()

{

    if (condicion si item seleccionado es mayor al id 0 de la tabla Muestra))

    {
     //habilitar listas
        listados.Enabled = true;
        llstatres.Enabled = true;
    }
    else 

    {
         //desabilitar

        listados.Enabled = false;
        listatres.Enabled = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: estas buscando selecteditem?

Comment: Me enrede con estos;DropDownList.SelectedValue, SelectedItem, SelectedIndex

Comment: Específicamente no se cual seria la propiedad correcta a utilizar y sus diferencias. Para usarlo en la condición claro esta.

Comment: `SelectedValue` regresa el valor asignado al item desde el Value Member, `SelectedItem` regresa la cadena actualmente seleccionada (El valor que es visible en el DropDown, el Display Member), `SelectedIndex` regresa el número del renglón del item seleccionado (del 0 al items-1 ).

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, me aclararon esa duda.